# What to pass when the type is `Record<string, File>`

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to upload some files and the data accepted type is
`Record<string, File>`

Here is the function

```
export class FileService {
  async uploadFile(
    fileId: string,
    {
      documents,
      checkbox,
    }: { documents?: Record<string, File>; checkbox?: boolean }
  ): Promise<FileEntry> {
    const form = new FormData();

    Object.entries(documents || {}).forEach(([k, file]) =>
      form.append(k, file, file.name)
    );
    return ...
  }
}
```

So you can see there are two variables `documents` and `checkbox`.
Checkbox is a boolean a value so I understand. What I am not clear is `Record<string, File>`

I tried passing the data like this for documents

```
FileService.uploadFile('testing', {
  documents: {
     "driverLicense": File{ "name": "testing.jpg", lastModified: 1234331, "size": 123},
     "signature": File {name: "testing.jpg", lastModified: 1234331, "size"123}
  },
  checkbox: true,
});
```

In the browser something like this

[image: data that is being posted]

But I always get 400 error. But when I try to pass documents as empty object its works.

```
   FileService.uploadFile('testing', {
      documents: {},
      checkbox: true,
    });
```

Does anyone know why I am failing?

Here is the api tested in post man which is working fine

[image: Post man test]

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (inputRef.current) {
          const listener = () => {
            const files: FileList | null | undefined = inputRef.current?.files;
           //File is being passed here
            if (files) {
              onFileChange(files[0]);
            }
          };
        }
        return () => {
          /* */
        };
      }, [onChange, onFileChange]);
```

Comment: Where are you actually allowing the user to select the file? Currently, you are creating a file object without having the actual binary at hand -- but i guess that was just for illustrative purposes?

Where does the actual request get made? Im assuming its using window.fetch. Is the content-type header set correctly to `form-data`?

Comment: Additionally, is there any more details on the error in the HTTP response body for the 400?

Comment: @AdamThomas I only got the message `unexpected field`. there is no additional message. I am not creating a file object. it was uploaded by clicking a upload button and save into state. I have updated the question

Comment: @AdamThomas I think the error is coming from the type `Record<string, File>` because the api is working correctly when passing empty object as documents

Comment: Possibly, though you should still check the content type. If you have no files, then it will use a different content type other than form-data. If you have files, but the wrong content-type, it'd blow up. Its probably not this but its something you should check.

Comment: One way you can debug this is you can use chrome inspector to look at your broken request. Then compare each and every header value in the request with the ones postman is uses, as well as the body -- and try to spot the differences.

Answer (score 0):

The type `Record<string, File>` means an object where the keys are strings and the values are `File` instances. You can't just pass an arbitrary object to those functions, it has to be an actual instance of the `File` class.

You should start by reading these:

- [Using files from web applications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_API/Using_files_from_web_applications)
- [Sending files using a FormData object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects#sending_files_using_a_formdata_object)

Comment: He did it for illustrative purposes I think (see comments on main question)